# How to download On demand Confluence page content image to local machine?

Tags: c#, confluence

I am new user for on demand confluence, i am able to read the page content using REST API

- https://{companyName}.atlassian.net/wiki/rest/prototype/1/content/524312?expand=attachments

I am find the image source link in this content like below

- https://{companyName}.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/524312/worddave1f7873c424d7824e580764369e7ee68.png

I am trying to download the images in the page content to local directory using the below c# coding

```
image=https://{companyName}.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/524312/worddave1f7873c424d7824e580764369e7ee68.png;
imageLocation =@"C:\Images";
string[] FileName = image.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx", "yyy");
client.DownloadFile(new Uri(image), imageLocation + "\\" + FileName[FileName.Count() - 1]);
```

I am not able to download the any images from on demand confluence page.

I also tried the below things
  1. I have manually export the particular page by "Export to HTML" from page operations in on demand confluence
  2. I have checked that export HTML zip file,  an attachment directory have the images in the particular page

I need to achieve my goal like above, please share your knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed my code like below, than i have downloaded the on demand confluence page content images to my local machine

```
image=https://{companyName}.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/524312/worddave1f7873c424d7824e580764369e7ee68.png;
imageLocation =@"C:\Images";
string[] FileName = image.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(new Uri(image+"?&os_username=xxx&os_password=yyy"), imageLocation + "\\" + FileName[FileName.Count() - 1]);
```